# LU decomposition in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to process LU decomposition in VHDL. I am a starter in VHDL. So I started implementing LU decomposition algorithm in MATLAB.

```
    a = [1 2 2;3 4 4;5 6 6];
    x=a;
    n=size(x,1);
    l=zeros(n,n);
    u=zeros(n,n);

    for k=1:n
        if (a(k,k)~=0)
            u(k,k)=x(k,k);
            l(k,k)=1;
        for i=k+1:n
            l(i,k)=x(i,k)/x(k,k);
            u(k,i)=x(k,i);
        end

        for i=k+1:n
            for j=k+1:n
                x(i,j)=x(i,j)-(l(i,k)*u(k,j));
            end
        end

        else break
        end

    end
```

Then I started doing this without for loop because for loop in vhdl doesn't work like matlab. Now, I am facing problem finding the equivalent code for the cascaded for loop.

```
a = [1 2 2;3 4 4;5 6 6];
x=a;
n=size(x,1);
l=zeros(n,n);
u=zeros(n,n);
k=1;
m=2;
j=2;
p=2;
for clock=1:100
if k>=1 && k<=n
    if (a(k,k)~=0)
        u(k,k)=x(k,k);
        l(k,k)=1;
    else disp('Decomposition not possible')
        return
    end
    if (m>=k+1 && m<=n)
        l(m,k)=x(m,k)/x(k,k);
        u(k,m)=x(k,m);
        m=m+1;
    end

    if p>=k+1 && p<=n
        if j>=k+1 && j<=n
            x(p,j)=x(p,j)-(l(p,k)*u(k,j));
            j=j+1;
        end
        if j==n+1
            p=p+1;
            j=2;
        end
    end    
end
    k=k+1;
end
```

I know the last code is not equivalent to the previous one. Can someone please help me with some hint on doing this in VHDL?

Comment: search for "matlab lu"?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to avoid loops in VHDL? Loops in hardware can be done in two ways: an iterative access over a single processing unit or performing operations in parallel. I would probably start by finding what's the basic step of LU decomposition that can be parallelized and iterate over it (e.g, processing a row or column at a time). Once you have a basic block working, you can go on and work on parallelizing that as well. Keep in mind the tradeoff between speedup and resource utilization. After all, it's hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Captain Obvious to the (title) rescue:

```
A = [1 2 2;3 4 4;5 6 6];
[L,U] = lu(A);
```

As for the *actual* question "can one implement a loop with `if`/`else` instead of `for`/`while`" (not very well reflected in the title though): yes, it is possible if the language allows `goto` statements. Loops are basically (un)conditional jumps *back* in the statement "stream". MATLAB is not one of those languages.

In a C-like language you can implement (declarations aside) a basic `for` loop like this:

```
        k = 0;

enter_loop:
        if(k < n) {
                /* here do in-loop stuff */
                k = k+1;
                goto enter_loop;
        }
```

*Note:* Your problem seems to be with VHDL. Why don't you change the question tags so VHDL people can answer it directly?

Comment: What about `while true` loop and `if - break` leaving conditions? Yes, I will mark such code as *Are You kidding me?*

Comment: @Crowley I thought that the point was avoiding language-supported loop statements. But it would be definitely a case of *Are you kidding me?* unless the code is written by Don Knuth: https://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~mak/CS185C/KnuthStructuredProgrammingGoTo.pdf :-)

Comment: I agree that **properly** written and optimized code with hacks is far better than ugly code written "right".